# Override default domain GPO with local policy

Tags: windows, server

Password complexity setting is disabled in default domain GPO. I need to enable it on one server, but I don't have the access to edit this GPO on the domain level. When I open local security settings on the server, option to enable (or disable) is grayed out. Is there a way to override default domain GPO for password complexity locally in the registry? And to keep it that way, to stop GPO from being propagated down from domain level to this particular server?

Comment: If you attach a GPO to the OU containing the server, that will (usually) override the settings in the Default Domain Policy GPO.  If there are other servers in the same OU, you may need to apply filtering to your GPO or move the server to a different OU.  There is no supported way to do this from the server itself, by design the information from the domain always takes precedence over local configuration.

Answer (score 0):

There are two moments in your case. First you can't use a local group policy for domain accounts because AD accounts store on only DCs. Only Domain Controller Polices. And ones apply only to user accounts. Not computer accounts. Second you can use a local group policy for edit settings for only local user accounts. Run the gpedit.msc command on local server for it.

But since Windows 2008 Domain you can separate password policy for different user groups. You can read about it here for example

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770842(v=ws.10).aspx

Good luck.